# Allow change URL, when Ajax query is running

Tags: php, ajax

i have a Apache2 server wich render three pages Projects, analysis and results

when the user go to the analysis.php page he can set some parameters and click a submit button with this code

```
$('#run_analysis_btn').on('click', function() {       
        $("#results_txt").append("<h3>Your job is running now</h3>");
        $("#results_txt").append("<img src='../images/loading.gif'>    </img>");
        var cov_min = $('#cov_min').val();
        var reference = $('#reference').val();
        var alt_fwd = $('#alt_fwd').val();
        var alt_rev = $('#alt_rev').val();
        var ref_fwd = $('#ref_fwd').val();
        var ref_rev = $('#ref_rev').val();
        var gt_qual = $('#gt_qual').val();
        var reference = $('#reference').val();
        var dataString = "MIN_COV=" + cov_min + "&ALT_FWD=" + alt_fwd + "&ALT_REV=" + alt_rev + "&REF_FWD=" + ref_fwd + "&REF_REV=" + ref_rev + "&GT_QUAL=" + gt_qual + "&REF=" + reference;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../php/run_analysis.php",
                async: true,
                format: "json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#results_txt").append(response);
                }
            });
    });
```

the run_analysis.php script has this two options so if the user change the page, i.e they wan't to go to the project.php o results.php page, the script end his job

```
<?php
// Ignore user aborts and allow the script
// To run X time
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
... work here
?>
```

and then start calling perl scripts and running some binaries to process files, for something like 3 minutes.

The problem is that if i the user want's to change the page from analysis.php to project.php, the page wait's until the ajax call end,
i put the async:true option, so what else can be wrong here?

thanks

Comment: Consider using a single page application framework, such as angular.

Comment: @IanP i was considering this, but i have all mi backend already in PHP

Comment: Back-end is irrelevant. Angular is a front-end framework :)